# How to exclude value from JavaRDD<String> before inserting into elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-streaming, rdd

I am Inserting JavaRDD into elastic search and I want to remove one value from it. I can't apply filter function as I need that value as a record id in elastic search

**{"elastic_search_id":"11","persona_email":"abc@gmail.com"}**

the code i am using is

```
Map confParent = new HashMap();

**// setting elasticsearch id**
confParent.put("es.mapping.id" , "elastic_search_id");

**// trying to remove key but not working**
confParent.put("es.mapping.exclude", "elastic_search_id");

confParent.put("es.resource" , index + "/" + type);

JavaEsSpark.saveJsonToEs(parentRecordsData,  confParent);
```

Comment: You want to store just the email of all documents or you want to remove the Id field from just the document you listed or you want to remove the entire document?

Comment: @sramalingam24 i just want to remove "elastic_search_id" from the document

Comment: The documentation states you need at least version 2.1 and not to specify es.input.json, other than that it should work

Comment: @sramalingam24 No its not working it gives exception org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: When writing data as JSON, the field exclusion feature is ignored. This is most likely not what the user intended. Bailing out

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?